# Getting Discourse Rails forum to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer, discourse

Anybody able to try and install [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) as a normal Rails app (no Docker) and see why it won't send emails from ones localhost SMTP server?

Sending emails from other Rails apps work just fine.

https://meta.discourse.org/t/emails-with-local-smtp/23645/16

Comment: I have setup a plain rails installation of Discourse before. For SMTP on localhost I used this: http://mailcatcher.me/

Comment: Did your email settings differ from the ones at https://meta.discourse.org/t/emails-with-local-smtp/23645/15?

Comment: Not sure. I just used this: https://github.com/pl3bs/dontdockmebro

Comment: So by using that, if registering your first user in Discourse, you will receive a welcome email to your localhost?

Comment: Assuming you setup mailcatcher and set that as your smtp settings.